# DB2 db2fm proccess

Tags: db2

Server is been up for 365 days, however i got some weird repeated procceses.

Are these normal?

ps -fea | grep db2fm

```
db2inst1  643284  229516  29   May 25      - 212564:06 /home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2fm -i db2inst1 -m /home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib/libdb2gcf.a -S
db2inst1  671770  229516  56   May 14      - 227447:02 /home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2fm -i db2inst1 -m /home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib/libdb2gcf.a -S
db2inst1  757794 1237058   0   Apr 19  pts/7  0:00 /bin/sh /home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2cc
db2inst1  774232  229516  30   Sep 25      - 94218:54 /home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2fm -i db2inst1 -m /home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib/libdb2gcf.a -S
db2inst1  962750  229516  30   Jul 18      - 145256:01 /home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2fm -i db2inst1 -m /home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib/libdb2gcf.a -S
db2inst1  999450  229516  29   Aug 17      - 117710:27 /home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2fm -i db2inst1 -m /home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib/libdb2gcf.a -S
db2inst1 1179898  229516  58   Nov 02      - 75788:49 /home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2fm -i db2inst1 -m /home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib/libdb2gcf.a -S
```

ps -fea | grep db2agent

```
db2inst1  409770  680100   0   Apr 19      -  0:00 db2agent (DATABASEA) 0
db2inst1  450750  778412   0   Apr 18      -  0:03 db2agent (idle) 0
db2inst1  618688  680100   0   Apr 19      -  0:00 db2agent (idle) 0
db2inst1  651440  680100   0   Nov 17      -  0:20 db2agent (DATABASEA) 0
db2inst1  655508  491676   0   Apr 19      -  0:04 db2agent (idle) 0
db2inst1  684038  680100   0   Mar 23      -  0:03 db2agent (DATABASEA) 0
db2inst1  790706  491676   0   Apr 19      -  0:00 db2agent (idle) 0
db2inst1  880672  680100   0   Apr 19      -  0:00 db2agent (DATABASEA) 0
db2inst1  913438  778412   0   Nov 16      -  0:20 db2agent (idle) 0
db2inst1  946182  491676   0   Apr 19      -  0:00 db2agent (DATABASEA) 0
db2inst1  991312  778412   0   Apr 17      -  0:16 db2agent (idle) 0
db2inst1 1077466  491676   0   Apr 19      -  0:00 db2agent (DATABASEA) 0
db2inst1 1134726  680100   0   Apr 19      -  0:00 db2agent (DATABASEA) 0
db2inst1 1142964  491676   0   Apr 19      -  0:00 db2agent (idle) 0
db2inst1 1233112  491676   0   Apr 19      -  0:00 db2agent (idle) 0
db2inst1 1261748  778412   0   Jun 15      -  0:18 db2agent (idle) 0
db2inst1 1384678  778412   0   Mar 23      -  0:27 db2agent (idle) 0
db2inst1 1404936  680100   0   Apr 19      -  0:00 db2agent (DATABASEA) 0
db2inst1 1421368  778412   0   Mar 22      -  0:04 db2agent (idle) 0
db2inst1 1445936  491676   0   Apr 19      -  0:00 db2agent (DATABASEA) 0
db2inst1 1482864  491676   0   Jun 16      -  0:31 db2agent (idle) 0
db2inst1 1503440  778412   0   Jun 15      -  0:56 db2agent (idle) 0
db2inst1 1519842  778412   0   Mar 23      -  0:00 db2agent (DATABASEA) 0
db2inst1 1531946  680100   0   Apr 19      -  0:00 db2agent (idle) 0
db2inst1 1572884  680100   0   Apr 19      -  0:00 db2agent (idle) 0
```

Other info

```
oslevel -g
Fileset                                 Actual Level        Maintenance Level
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
bos.rte                                 5.3.0.40            5.3.0.0

db2fm -s -S
Gcf module 'fault monitor' is NOT operable
Gcf module '/home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib/libdb2gcf.a' state is AVAILABLE


uptime
  02:14PM   up 365 days,  12:51,  6 users,  load average: 6.69, 6.89, 6.97

 db2level
DB21085I  Instance "db2inst1" uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL08020"
with level identifier "03010106".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v8.1.1.64", "s040812", "U498350", and FixPak "7"
```

Answer (score 0):

db2fm is the Fault Monitor process and it fires up at least once per instance.

db2agent will probably fire up more than once because you can have more than one agent running per connection.

So to me this looks normal.

A good reference for this is the article "[Everything You Wanted to Know About DB2 Universal Database Processes](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0304chong/0304chong.html)" on developerworks.

Comment: db2fm is actually a utility used to control the fault monitor daemon, db2fmd. Judging by the fact that there are no db2fmd processes shown I would say this is not at all normal, because the daemon itself is not running, while multiple instances of the utility invoked to check its status (db2fm -S) hang in there. More info here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008306.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks pretty normal for a server with a handful of databases with 5 or so clients per database.